# Making a static field final in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, static, jndi, final

Looking at the following code snippet, the scenario given is about fetching a database connection from a database connection pool in the Tomcat Server.

```
public final class DatabaseConnection {

    private static DataSource dataSource;

    static {
        try {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context context = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
            dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/assignment_db");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

I would like making the only field in the class `final`. If I make it a `final` field then, the compiler complains,

> variable dataSource might not have been initialized.

After making it `final`, if it is initialized to `null` at the declaration place then, further initialization of this field in the `try` block is severely forbidden causing a compilation error,

> cannot assign a value to final variable dataSource.

`NamingException` is a checked exception. Hence, it must be caught or declared to be thrown.

---

Earlier, there was a different scenario. The strategy was to use Apache DBCP as follows.

```
public final class DatabaseConnection {

    private static final BasicDataSource basicDataSource;

    static {
        basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/assignment_db");
        basicDataSource.setUsername("Tiny");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("root");
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return basicDataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

In which, the field could be declared `final` because there is no checked exception and `try...catch` is unnecessary.

Can I somehow make `dataSource` final as in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has got me stuck many times, until I found out a workaround. You can use a temporary variable in the `static` block, and assign the `dataSource` after `try-catch` ends using that variable:

```
private static final DataSource dataSource;

static
{
    DataSource tempDataSource = null;
    try
    {                
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context context = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
        tempDataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/assignment_db");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    dataSource = tempDataSource;
}
```

However, I would rather not follow normally, and throw the exception from the `catch` block only if `dataSource` is not initialized, in which case, you won't need a local variable:

```
static
{
    try
    {                
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context context = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/assignment_db");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("dataSource not initialized");
    }
}
```

Comment: I could never imagine this. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Tiny You can in fact throw any unchecked throwable...The thread would wrap it in a java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: @AbhinavKumar : Indeed but as a beginner, I did not know this prior to this post. Thanks.

Comment: Everyone is beginner once.. :)